# timestamp conversion

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have uploader.php that will up the thousands of data from .csv going to mysql database.

my scenario are: after i upload all data in .csv i will convert it to mysql readable data types. question is

Any ideas how to convert the datatype from **18-Feb-13 6:19:41 PM** data from .csv file to readable data in mysql.

for example: **2013-02-18 18:19:41**

Note: I do not wish to edit the timestamp in excel file from readable format in mysql.

many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` :
assuming your date is in a variable called CSV in col 1 :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y G:i:s A',$csv[1]);
$query = "INSERT INTO yourtable(yourdate) VALUES(".$date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s').")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$dat="18-Feb-13 6:19:41 PM";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($dat));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$timestamp = strtotime($csv_date);
```

in PHP and then in mysql query you can do the following:

```
... FROM_UNIXTIME(' . $timestamp . ') ...
```